# Can you use the Fabricate spell as part of creating magical items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you use the Fabricate spell as part of creating magical items?

Comment: Jhyarelle, it would help to provide some explanation of work you've done and where you're stuck when you would otherwise be writing a one-sentence question like this. Do you mean as in using Fabricate to do the crafting, or to produce the materials, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are creating a magic item that requires the [Fabricate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate) spell as one of its requirements, like a [Robe of Useful Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-of-useful-items/).

Yes, you can use the objects created by the [Fabricate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate) spell, as those items are permanent and will cost you a similar amount of money as if you had bought the necessary materials to craft the item. The spell is simply accelerating the process, which is the point.

> Components V, S, M (the original material, which **costs the same amount as the raw materials** required to craft the item to be created)

No, if you want to create a magic item using the [Fabricate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate) spell because the spell explicitly forbids such thing. From the spell description:

> Creatures or magic items cannot be created or transmuted by the fabricate spell.